# Error in positive lookbehind and positive lookahead regex - python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex

`(?i)(?<=\b(?:host)\s*(?:name)\s*[-|:|=|\s]\s*)(?=.*[^\s][\d\_\-\.].*)([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\._\-\'\"]{5,})`

Here I am trying to find hostname values in the regex.
My requirements are:

1. hostname should have a digit or _ or - or . in them
2. hostname can consist of alphabets digits ( ) . _ - ' "
3. The pattern for hostname is

   `hostname: test123` or  `hostname= test123` or `hostname- test123` or `hostname test123`

   `host name: test123` or  `host name= test123` or `host name- test123` or `host name test123`

   `hostname : test123` or  `hostname = test123` or `hostname - test123` or `hostname test123` etc

So that is why I have chosen the above mentioned regex to include positive lookbehind and positive lookahead assertion

I have two examples:

Input1: `host name : en.wikipedia.org is a correct example`

Input2: `Verify that the hostname installation configures the system.`

Input1 is a correct example as the detected string `en.wikipedia.org` contains `.` whereas the detection of `installation` in Input2 is a invalid detection as does not contains digit or _ or .

But with the above regex a `.` at the end of the sentence in Input2 the regex matches.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem yet, but this can work for you:

```
host\s?name\s?[:|=|\-|\s]\s?(?=.*)(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d|[a-zA-Z]*[.-_])([\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=\s|$)
```

refer to the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/HFc1HG/1)

you will need to use groups to get the hostname out of the matches.

Comment: This solution matches with pattern and hostname. 
So in the example 

`Verify that host name : en.wikipedia.org is a correct example`

This will match with `host name : en.wikipedia.org` where i need to match with only `en.wikipedia.org`

Comment: that is why you will need to use groups as it gives multiple matches. In the demo see the group 1 match in the right panel